# Hexagono com css - imagem embaçada

Tags: css

Após muitas tentativas consegui transformar uma imagem em um hexágono somente com CSS, tive muitos problemas com SVG, js, etc.

Porém, a imagem esta perfeita no IE (por incrível que pareça) e no Chrome ela distorce um pouco, no Firefox distorce muito!

Segue código:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.hexagono {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  transform: scale(1.25, .707) rotate(-45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.hexagono > img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.8, 1.404);
  clip: rect(0, 120px, 200px, 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagono">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZNRZUaQ.png" />
</div>
```

[Exemplo online.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwbPMp)

Alguém saberia uma alternativa para não embaçar a imagem?

Comment: Os atributos do seu **CSS** comentados [aqui](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waoQgG) é que estão causando a perda de qualidade da imagem, principalmente o `scale` na imagem. Mas como você pode ver sem eles o exemplo se tornou um octógono ao invés de um hexágono, hehe.

Comment: Obrigado, Fernando!
Estou fazendo alguns testes... Sem sucesso por enquanto!
Rs.
Abraços!

Answer (score 6):

Podes fazer o pretendido das seguintes maneiras,
utilizando a `<img>` tag como já tens na tua pergunta, ou usando a imagem como background.
Eis um exemplo usando a `<img>` tag:

```css
.hexagono  {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:table;
}
.hexagono:before {
    content:'';
    padding-top:120%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.hexagono:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:-10%;
    width:120%;
    padding-top:120%;
    transform: rotatex(51deg) rotate(45deg);
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 200px white;;
}
.hexagono img {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0 -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagono">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZNRZUaQ.png"/>
</div>
```

Ou se preferires o segundo método, podemos fazer isto utilizando a imagem como background como no exemplo abaixo. Vou deixar aqui também um link para um exemplo online no jsFiddle adicionalmente com vários exemplos e uma outra forma de hexagono: http://jsfiddle.net/qqy26d3e/

```css
.hexagono {
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.imagem1{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.imagem2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZNRZUaQ.png);
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.um {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagono um">
    <div class="imagem1">
        <div class="imagem2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

O seu CSS não funciona bem no Chrome e no Firefox porque a propriedade `transform` ainda não é standard no CSS para funcionar em todos os browsers necessitamos de adicionar um prefixo à propriedade.

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 57.74px;
  margin: 28.87px 0;
  background-image: url(http://csshexagon.com/img/meow.jpg);
  background-size: auto 115.4701px;
  background-position: center;
}

.hexTop,
.hexBottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70.71px;
  height: 70.71px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background: inherit;
  left: 14.64px;
}

/*counter transform the bg image on the caps*/
.hexTop:after,
.hexBottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100.0000px;
  height: 57.73502691896258px;
  -webkit-transform:  rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-28.8675px);
  -ms-transform:      rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-28.8675px);
  transform:          rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-28.8675px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.hexTop {
  top: -35.3553px;
}

.hexTop:after {
  background-position: center top;
}

.hexBottom {
  bottom: -35.3553px;
}

.hexBottom:after {
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.0000px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100.0000px;
  height: 57.7350px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">
  <div class="hexTop"></div>
  <div class="hexBottom"></div>
</div>
```

**Fonte:**
http://csshexagon.com/